# Acesso a pasta do windows server pelo PHP em Linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, windows

Temos uma intranet desenvolvida em PHP que fica dentro de um servidor Linux com apache. Preciso acessar uma pasta que esta em outro servidor e esse servidor é Windows. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Olá, você pode configurar uma conexão ftp para este servidor com o PHP, ou até mesmo sftp. Segue os links domanual do PHP para realizar essas conexões: SFTP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp.php FTP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.ftp.php

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?